# what type of jazz guitar is this, and how can I learn it?

Tags: guitar, jazz

I really love this type of sound, and quiet solos, what is it called this style?

When I type jazz guitar, I usually get something that sounds like elevator music.

I would love to know how to get started playing this type of guitar as well, is it electric?

I have classical guitar training for less than a year...but that video is what I would like to aim for.

thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, chord-melody playing.  One usually harmonizes (or re-harmonizes) all the melody notes (or at least most of 'em) so that a chord is formed for each.
Very demanding; one not only needs a good grounding in theory but also in chord structure, inversions, substitutions, and so forth.
Usually played fingerstyle.... Joe Pass was a master.

There are a number of dedicated forums for the style.

I had a couple of this guy's books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Contemporary-Chord-Solos-Simplified-Substitute/dp/0793524148/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319997280&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0793524148)

They are an excellent primer on the style if you can find 'em.

Comment: Good luck. This is the most demanding and difficult technique in guitar playing.

Comment: Just a few names for you to look for - Joe Pass already got a mention, but Barney Kessel, Howard Roberts, Herb Ellis, Tal Farlow, Toots Thielmans, Martin Taylor are all worth a listen. To be honest, the monster guitarist in this style was Julian Bream, but his jazz recordings are hard to find - the classical stuff swamps any web search you make.